# %0D wget with php

Tags: php, bash

I am working on a personnal project whose allow me to wget files from web.

I have a problem, all filenames have a %0D at the end exept the last in the list.

Here is my code :

index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea name="directlink" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
    </form>
</html>
```

action.php :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['directlink'])) {
    $file = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['directlink']);
    $files = explode("\n", $file);
    foreach ($files as $value) {
    $final[] = base64_encode($value);
    }
$file = implode(" ", $final);
shell_exec('sudo -u user download/wget.sh ' . 'option' . ' ' . $file);
}

?>
```

Wget.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

/download/wget_cmd.sh "$@" 2>&1
```

Wget_cmd.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in ${@:2}
do
    file=$(echo -n "${i}" | base64 --decode)
    wget "$file" -P /download/ 2>&1
done
```

Comment: Um, `wget.sh` should simply be `/download/wget_cmd.sh "$@" 2>&1`. And why does `wget_cmd.sh` just ignore its first argument?

Comment: Because It's not the complete script, I am doing some treatment with the option. I don't know why I am doing 2 bash script, thank you x) But the problem is the same, I have %0D too

Comment: Ok with only one script, I need to wait on the webpage. I need 2 scripts for launch wget in background. If you have another method..  Thank you for the "$@" tips ^^

Comment: This sounds like a windows-style (crlf) / unix style (lf) line ending issue, have you transferred any stuff from windows in binary mode?

Comment: No, I don't use any windows binary mode, you can have the problem with the code that I have provide ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explode the textarea raw data by `\n`. If the user uses Windows you'll end up with `\r`'s all around. You possibly want to [preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split) instead:

```
$files = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $file);
```

... then maybe trim each file:

```
foreach ($files as $value) {
    $final[] = base64_encode(trim($value));
}
```

*P.S. PHP can do HTTP just fine, there's no really need for an external command.*